# Starting/Stopping AWS EC2 Instances using AWS Powershell Tools

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

I am attempting to write two separate scripts. One script determines which EC2 instances are stopped, it starts them and documents what it starts to a text file.

The second script will read the text file and stop those instances. For debugging/simplicty sake I am starting out by combining the two scripts into a single script.

Here's my script:

```
$Instances = (Get-EC2Instance).instances
$start_instances = @()
$Instances | foreach { 
    $state = Get-EC2InstanceStatus -InstanceId $_.InstanceId  -IncludeAllInstance $true 
    $state = $state.InstanceState.Name

    if ($state -eq "stopped"){
        $start_instances += $_.InstanceId
    }
} 
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\users\myusername\desktop\so.csv", $($start_instances  -join ','))

$shutdown_instances = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\users\myusername\desktop\so.csv")

Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

Stop-EC2Instance -Instance $shutdown_instances
```

Starting and documenting what instances are running works fine. Its the stopping instances which is failing.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Stop-EC2Instance : Invalid id: "i-99edd755,i-8d647f58"
At C:\users\myusername\Desktop\aws-test.ps1:28 char:1
+ Stop-EC2Instance -Instance $shutdown_instances
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Stop-EC2Instance], AmazonEC2Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.EC2.AmazonEC2Exception,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.EC2.StopEC2InstanceCmdl
```

Those instance IDs are indeed valid so I can't figure out why the heck its complaining. I was writing the instance IDs to a file via out-file and getting it via get-content but that seemed to have caused a different error.

I'm assuming the issue has something to do with the format of the data once i'm pulling it out of the text file.

**Edit**
So I've changed my script to:

```
 $start_instances = $start_instances | Select-Object @{Name='Name';Expression={$_}}
 $start_instances | Export-Csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation -path C:\temp\instances.csv

 $stop_instances = @(Import-Csv -path C:\temp\instances.csv)

 $stop_instances | Stop-EC2Instance
```

But still get an error:

```
Stop-EC2Instance : No instances specified
At C:\temp\aws-test.ps1:22 char:19
+ $stop_instances | Stop-EC2Instance
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Stop-EC2Instance], AmazonEC2Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.EC2.AmazonEC2Exception,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.EC2.StopEC2InstanceCmdlet
```

I've also tried:

```
Stop-EC2Instance -InstanceID $stop_instances
```

But that also dies:

```
Stop-EC2Instance : No instances specified
At C:\temp\aws-test.ps1:22 char:1
+ Stop-EC2Instance -InstanceId $stop_instances
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Stop-EC2Instance], AmazonEC2Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.EC2.AmazonEC2Exception,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.EC2.StopEC2InstanceCmdlet
```

Comment: The message certainly sounds like it sees this string: `i-99edd755,i-8d647f58` as a single ID value, instead of two separated values. It seems that it doesn't like your CSV format.

Comment: If I comment out the line that reads in the data from the CSV file and instead feed it the variable I wrote to the text file it works as expected. So for example: Stop-EC2Instance -Instance $start_instances works as expected. Of course that's not a valid solution for me as I need to split these into two separate scripts. The second script (the shutdown script) won't have access to that variable. Thus why I'm writing the instance names to a file to begin with.

Comment: Not sure what any of that has to do with my comment. Are you able to set multiple IDs in a single variable and get that to work?

Comment: Outside of my script if I do Stop-EC2Instance -Instance i-99edd755,i-8d647f58 it works

Comment: Mark B is right.  The InstanceId parameter takes an array of IDs.  You're handing it one long string of IDs separated by commas.  That's not what it wants.  Try splitting them, adding them to an array and then passing that in to Stop-EC2Instance.  Also, you do realize there's an Import-CSV cmdlet, right?

Comment: If Stop-EC2Instance won't except a string of IDs seperated by commas, then why does this work: Stop-EC2Instance -Instance i-99edd755,i-8d647f58? Whats the difference between using a variable which is a string of comma separated IDs, or manually typing in a comma separated list of IDs?

Comment: @Brad Powershell implicitly assumes your string is a single unit and adds it as a unit to the array the cmdlet is expecting.  When you type them out into the cmdlet as you have here, Powershell interprets them as individual units and adds each separately into the expected array.  If you were to put quotes around them in your example, it would fail because it would assume "i-99edd755,i-8d647f58" is single unit rather than two distinct units.

Comment: Se above I modified the script to use import/export-csv. Also tried to pass Stop-EC2Instance an array. Still no joy.

Comment: @Brad  I tried it too.  Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

InstanceId parameter needs array.

You can declare an empty array first

```
$EC2Instance =@()
```

Then use Import-CSV and pipe it to append the empty array with each value from csv

```
Import-CSV C:\Temp\Instance.csv | Foreach-Object {$EC2Instance += $_.InstanceId}

echo $EC2Instance
```

$EC2instance will now have the required instance id's in an array

Then you can use it in the command

```
Stop-EC2instance -InstanceId $EC2instance
```

This worked for me.